# Where does the code pulled down by git jenkins go?

Tags: macos, git, jenkins

I have a jenkins git job to pull down code from github. Jenkins tells me the job / project is successful. But I can't see the code anywhere on my file system (osx).

Where should it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you used the default location for the `JENKINS_HOME` directory where Jenkins stores all its data, the code should be under

```
/Users/jenkins_user/.jenkins/job_name/workspace
```

where jenkins_user is the account that runs the Jenkins server and job_name s the name of your build job.

Additionally, within the first few lines of the "Console Output" for any build, you should see on which machine and in which directory the build occurred, e.g.
"Building on master in workspace /Users/jenkins_user/.jenkins/job_name/workspace"